# Embedded iframe video overlap the fixed navbar while Scrolling

Tags: html, css

I'm a complete beginner in programming. Currently working on a Product landing page. I embedded a video from youtube using an iframe and made my navbar fixed at the top. While scrolling down the video is sliding over the navbar. What should I do to make the video scroll down the navbar like the rest of the page content?

Here is the code of HTML file:

```
    <div class="logo">
      <img id="header-img" src="http://www.logodust.com/img/free/logo2.png" alt="Company Logo" title="comapany logo">
      <h1>
        Pilot - Capless Since 1984
      </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#container">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutUs">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#products">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact-info">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</header>

<div class="container">

  <section class="videoWrapper">
    <iframe id="video" width="600" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/l__LJ8NF6eQ" frameborder="0"
allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
      </section>
</div>
```

CSS code of navbar:

```
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #05386B;
  color: #EDF5E1;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.logo #header-img {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.logo h1 {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

CSS code for iframe:

```
.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 35%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.videoWrapper iframe {
  border: 5px solid #05386B;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5em;
  bottom: 2em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some missing code in your above code. You might have missed it when copy/pasting? I've added it back in my answer. However, always good to try and make your question as answerable as possible. Hope my answer helps and good luck with learning programming :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### z-index on Header And Video

You have missing code `<header>` in your above code. Also, there is no ID for the header as it's not there, so I've added the missing code and added the header style as the CSS HTML element `header`.

[image]

I've added a z-index of 0 to `.videoWrapper iframe` and a z-index of 1 to `header` I also added a light grey background to your header so you can see the result better.

### What is a z-index?

The z-index is how you determine the layer order in the box model of HTML. The higher the number, the higher on top it is.

---

Hope this helps and good luck with your project :)

[image]

```
    <style>
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:1;
  background:#ddd;
}

#nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #05386B;
  color: #EDF5E1;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.logo #header-img {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.logo h1 {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 35%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.videoWrapper iframe {
  border: 5px solid #05386B;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5em;
  bottom: 2em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index:0;
}

    </style>
<header>    
    <div class="logo">
      <img id="header-img" src="http://www.logodust.com/img/free/logo2.png" alt="Company Logo" title="comapany logo">
      <h1>
        Pilot - Capless Since 1984
      </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#container">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutUs">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#products">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact-info">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</header>

<div class="container">

  <section class="videoWrapper">
    <iframe id="video" width="600" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/l__LJ8NF6eQ" frameborder="0"
allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
      </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Your welcome. If you found this answered your question, please upvote and mark as answered using the tick selection. Many thanks, Alex :)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, add `z-index` property. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) is a reference for this proprety.

```
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```